# Is it possible to develop with MassTransit in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, masstransit

I'm a casual developer and typically use VB.Net when writing solutions, as its what I'm most familiar with. Though I aim to learn other languages in the future, such as C#, its very much on the back-burner and so here we are.

One of my current projects would benefit greatly from a service-bus architecture, so I have been researching potential options.  Some of the more obvious choices, such as Azure Service Bus, are out of the question, as my application will not have access to the public internet once operational.  Looking in to options that could be run within a local site I've stumbled across both nServiceBus & MassTransit as front runners.

My current stumbling block is that all the documentation and sample code seems to be written for C#.  My question would be if the frameworks require programming to take place in C# exclusively, or whether I can utilise another .NET language (such as VB) instead.  If this is indeed possible, I wonder if anyone could point me in the direction of some sample code? Of course I can gradually reverse engineer the C# if necessary, once I know if VB development is even possible (or practical).

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: If it's a .NET library then it can be used by any .NET application, regardless of the language in which that application is written.  So, yes, you can write a VB application which references a library written in C#.

Comment: .NET is .NET, so technically it should be usable. I know F# teams that use MassTransit. As for VB.NET, I don't have any idea, but it _should_.

Comment: That's the beauty of the [.NET CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr): once you've created an assembly in _one_ language, you can use/reference it in every _other_ .NET project/language. For C# to VB.NET or vice versa translation, I found [this site](https://sites.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) to be a useful resource to me.

Comment: FWIW: I did use VB.Net back in the early days of the project. Ultimately, the syntax may be a bit weird since the project is def built with C# aesthetics in mind.

Comment: You don't need to "reverse engineer" the C# just convert whatever sample code you have to VB syntax. Chances are you could even use an online converter.

Comment: I am not familiar with VB but a couple of years ago I helped a VB dev to the basics; start a bus for sending, send a message. It was straightforward without problem. I used this c#/VB code convertor to help with this : https://converter.telerik.com/